# LT1072 diagram interpretation

Tags: circuit-design, datasheet

I'm making a circuit based on an application shown in the [LT1072 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1072fc.pdf). But I'm having trouble interpreting the text where it explains how to change the circuit for lower input voltages. If the anode of D3 is connected to Vin, where does the cathode go? It can't go to ground with R5 removed, because that will short circuit the supply.

[image]

Comment: I suspect when they say connect D3 anode to VIN they mean to the VIN voltage, not the VIN pin. The cathode would stay connected to the VIN pin.

Comment: @td127 And so short the Vin and Vsw pins?

Comment: No, remove R5 entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quiescent current of the IC is about 6 mA and probably even higher at start up. With the original schematic that causes a voltage drop of 3 V and potentially more at start up.

This is what the datasheet is suggesting for low input voltages:
[image: lt1072 ibb paintover]

So you are supplying the input voltage to the Vin-pin using a diode instead of a resistor to significantly decrease the voltage drop.